# What's the difference between "stock exchange" & "stack exchange"( the name of this network of Q&A websites )?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What's the difference between "stock exchange" & "stack exchange"( the name of this network of Q&A websites ) & "stock market"?

I know that [stock exchange](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stock-market?s=t) means:

> The business of buying and selling shares and the place where this happens ( also called **stock market** )

And also I searched for the word [stack](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stack?s=t):

> a neat pile of things

But actually I did not find the relation of this word with the name of this website, which is "stack exchange".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pun. Stack in computing terms is a storage unit for a virtual 'pile' of data objects, and a Stock Exchange is a place where profitable companies become more valuable and unprofitable ones become less valuable. The first users of Stack Exchange were software developers, and the system (of better answers rising to the top and bad ones filtering down) somewhat simulates the movement of the stock market.

Comment: Really great answer, the only thing I'd recommend in ELL is to backup definitions with dictionary references where possible (such as the meaning of "stack" being a computing term). But welcome to ELL.

Comment: A professional answer, an innovative idea!